# NumPy 1.8.0 for Python 3.3.3 Windows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have Python 3.3.3 installed on Windows 7, and I would like to install NumPy 1.8.0, which is currently the latest release. However, on the SourceForge [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/) there is no Windows installer listed. There appears to be a build at [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), namely numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe, but the site mentions that there some compatibility problems with SciPy.

Should I just download the MKL build, or is there a Python 3.3 NumPy 1.8.0 Windows build somewhere else online?

Comment: Have you tried installing winpython, and then loading the new numpy through its settings utility? It should work. Of course, if there is a code incompatibility with scipy, you're screwed.

Answer (score 1):

you can find a working version of numpy1.8.1 for python3.3 64bit here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score 0):

It says that there are compatibility problems with the *official* Windows binaries of SciPy. I assume "official" refers to what you download from http://scipy.org/scipylib/download.html.
Just use the (unofficial) SciPy binaries hosted on Christoph Gohlke's useful site.

Comment: I'd +1 his site, if I could.

Comment: Just to save some folks searching for the mentioned side: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/